# Hibernate search highlighting not analyzed fields

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'd like to highlight the whole not analyzed fields if they match the search query.
The indexed entity looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(
        name = "documentAnalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(
                        factory = StopFilterFactory.class,
                        params = {
                                @Parameter(name = "words", value = "stoplist.properties"),
                                @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true")
                        }
                )
        }
)
public class Document {

    ...

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private String notAnalyzedField; // has "x-xxx-xxx" format

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.YES)
    private String analyzedField;   

}
```

Suppose I have a `Document` with `notAnalyzedField: "a-bbb-ccc"`, then I run a search query with the same value and highlight search results using the following code:

```
String highlightText(Query query, Analyzer analyzer, String fieldName, String text) {
    QueryScorer queryScorer = new QueryScorer(query);
    SimpleHTMLFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<span>", "</span>");
    Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, queryScorer);
    return highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, fieldName, text);
}
```

As a result I get the following snippet:`"a-<span>bbb</span>-<span>ccc</span>"`.
And it seems reasonable because the analyzer treats `a` symbol as a stop word and `-` as a delimiter and doesn't highlight them. But I cannot figure out how I can avoid using analyzer while highlighting this field. There are a few methods in `Highlighter` class that require `TokenStream` instead of `Analyzer` but I'm not sure how to use them.

A result I want to achieve is the whole highlighted field: `"<span>a-bbb-ccc</span>"`
Is there a way to achieve this with hibernate-search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does your analyzer come from?

You might want to get it from Hibernate Search:

```
FullTextEntityManager em = /*...*/;
Analyzer analyzer = em.getSearchFactory()
    .getAnalyzer(Document.class);
highlightText(query, analyzer, fieldName, text);
```

If it doesn't work, try using a `KeywordAnalyzer`: `highlightText(query, new KeywordAnalyzer(), fieldName, text);`

Comment: I've updated the question with the definition of a custom analyzer that I use. Its primary goal is to have a custom stopwords list. It's used in highlighting process. The KeywordAnalyzer didn't work for me in this case.

Comment: @IlyaZinkovich You said you didn't want the analyzer to be used, and that you wanted the whole text to be highlighted, and now you are saying you want to use custom stopwords, which implies analysis. It seems a bit contradictory... ? What result did you get with the KeywordAnalyzer, and what exactly is wrong with this result?

Comment: The field that needs to be highlighted is not analyzed, but the analyzer is still present since it's used for all other fields. I've tried to use KeywordAnalyzer only on highlighting stage, but it didn't highlight anything.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what you're doing but you are probably passing bad parameters to your method (the query, the text, ...). I tried your code separately with a `KeywordAnalyzer`, and it worked as expected: https://gist.github.com/yrodiere/b2f70e88f2f9700715867c4de25c1732 . Please tell me what you mean exactly when you say "it didn't work", or I can't help you.

Comment: @Yoannn, thanks a lot for your help. The problem was that I used different analyzers for indexing and highlighting. I additionally patched my custom analyzer with PatternTokenizer adding full strings with the x-xxx-xxxx format to the index.