# How can I get the highlights of my result set in Hibernate search 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, fuzzy-search, hibernate-search-6

I am using Hibernate search 6 Lucne backend in my java application.

There are various search operations I am performing including a fuzzy search.

I get search results without any issues.

Now I want to show what are the causes to pick each result in my result list.

Let's say the search keyword is "test", and the fuzzy search is performed in the fields "name", "description", "Id" etc. And I get 10 results in a List. Now I want to highlight the values in the fields of each result which caused that result to be a matching result.

eg: Consider the below to be one of the items in the search result List object. (for clarity I have written it in JSON format)

```
 {  
    name:"ABC some test name",
    description: "this is a test element",
    id: "abc123"
}
```

As the result suggests it's been picked as a search result because the keyword "test" is there in both the fields "name" and the "description". I want to highlight those specific fields in the frontend when I show the search results.

Currently, I am retrieving search results through a java REST API to my Angular frontend. How can I get those specific fields and their values using Hibernate search 6 in my java application?

So far I have gone through Hibernate search 6 documentation and found nothing. (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#preface) Also looked at what seemed to be related issues on the web over the past week and got nothing so far. It seems like m requirement is a little specific and that's why I need your help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Highlighting is not yet implemented in Hibernate Search, see [HSEARCH-2192](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2192).</s> => Starting with Hibernate Search 6.2, it is! See https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.2/#search-highlighting, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-highlighting

---

Old answer:

That being said, you can leverage native Elasticsearch / Lucene APIs.

With Elasticsearch it's relatively easy: you can use a [request transformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-query-elasticsearch-json) to add a [`highlight` element](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting) to the HTTP request, then use the [`jsonHit` projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-extensions-elasticsearch-jsonHit) to retrieve the JSON for each hit, which contains a `highlight` element that includes the highlighted fields and the highlighted fragments.

With Lucene it would be more complex and you'll have to rely on unsupported features, but that's doable.

Retrieve the Lucene `Query` from your Hibernate Search predicate:

```java
SearchPredicate predicate = ...;
Query query = LuceneMigrationUtils.toLuceneQuery(predicate);
```

Then do the highlighting: [Hibernate search highlighting not analyzed fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673242/hibernate-search-highlighting-not-analyzed-fields/47679943#47679943) may help with that, so that code uses an older version of Lucene and you might have to adapt it:

```java
String highlightText(Query query, Analyzer analyzer, String fieldName, String text) {
    QueryScorer queryScorer = new QueryScorer(query);
    SimpleHTMLFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<span>", "</span>");
    Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, queryScorer);
    return highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, fieldName, text);
}
```

You'll need to add a depdency to `org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter`.

To retrieve the analyzer, use the Hibernate Search metadata: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-access-analyzers

So, connecting the dots... something like that?

```java
Highlighter createHighlighter(SearchPredicate predicate, SearchScope<?> scope) {
    // Taking a shortcut here to retrieve the index manager,
    // since we already have the scope
    // WARNING: This only works when searching a single index
    Analyzer analyzer = scope.includedTypes().iterator().next().indexManager()
            .unwrap( LuceneIndexManager.class )
            .searchAnalyzer(); 

    // WARNING: this method is not supported and might disappear in future versions of HSearch
    Query query = LuceneMigrationUtils.toLuceneQuery(predicate);
    QueryScorer queryScorer = new QueryScorer(query);
    SimpleHTMLFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<span>", "</span>");
    return new Highlighter(formatter, queryScorer);
}
```

```java
SearchSession searchSession = Search.session( entityManager ); 

SearchScope<Book> scope = searchSession.scope( Book.class ); 
SearchPredicate predicate = scope.predicate().match() 
                .fields( "title", "authors.name" )
                .matching( "refactoring" )
                .toPredicate();

Highlighter highlighter = createHighlighter(predicate, scope);

// Using Pair from Apache Commons, but others would work just as well
List<Pair<Book, String>> hits = searchSession.search( scope )
        .select( select( f -> f.composite(
                // Highlighting the title only, but you can do the same for other fields
                book -> Pair.of( book, highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, "title", book.getTitle()))
                f.entity()
        ) )
        .where( predicate )
        .fetch( 20 );
```

Not sure this compiles, but that should get you started.

---

Relatedly, but not exactly what you're asking for, there's an `explain` feature to get a sense of why a given hit has a given score: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-query-explain

Comment: Hi, @yrodiere thank you very much for the direction. I'll try this out and share my experience here.